# iphone Detect selected MKPinAnnotation in a MapView

Tags: iphone, ios4, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I have a custom MKPinAnnotation in which I have added a couple of peroperties , like the Id of the object and the type. What I want is when someone selects a pin in the MapView to detect which pin is selected and get that data.

And Show a button on its view to use that data in the button's action.

Can anyone help with this? I can't find how to detect if (and which) an annotation is selected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is already a built in method to take care of this situation for you.  You need to use the method below.  The view.annotation is the annotation that was tapped.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView 
 annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    NSLog(@"The annotation tapped is: %@", view.annotation.title);
}
```

Edit:  It can be found here, the API is your friend.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008204

Comment: I managed to get the selected pin using the accessoryControlTapped method you told me. The problem now is that my annotation is a custom MKPinAnnotation ( sorry if I mispelled) and it has a property called objectId. I want to get that Id. So i try to Cast the selected annotation to MapPinAnnotation and then get the id, but it returns null.

Comment: The Code I'm using is : 

' - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    NSLog(@"The annotation tapped is: %@", view.annotation.title);
    if ( [view.annotation isKindOfClass:[MapPinViewAnnotation class]] ) {
        MapPinViewAnnotation *selectedAnnotation = (MapPinViewAnnotation *) view.annotation;
        selectedId = selectedAnnotation.objectId;
        NSLog(@"Selected ID is : %@" , selectedId);
        //do something and go to next view code here
    }
}'